# Excel 2016 -How do I seach for the value in workbook 1 cell A1 in workbook 2 range $G:$R?

Tags: excel

Excel 2016 - Excel workbook 1 has in A:A a list of values; a different Excel workbook may have one of those values in column $G:$K. How do I seach for the value in workbook 1 cell A1 in workbook 2 range $G:$R?

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Begin with this and change it to suit your needs:

```
Sub JustOneCell()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

    Set r1 = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set r2 = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:R")
    Set r3 = r2.Find(What:=r1.Value, After:=r2(1))

    MsgBox r3.Address
End Sub
```